# How to input ⑮⑭⑬ (unicode symbols with a number in a circle) when typing?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I saw somebody rename their Pokemon in *Pokemon Go* using numbers in a circle, such as "Dratini⑮⑭⑬"

I can only think of copy and paste, but you always have to find a document that has these characters and copy from there and paste it in *Pokemon Go*.

How can it be done? Is there a faster/direct way?

Comment: Tried **[Unicode Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.hotmist.unicodepad)** ??

Comment: You need a custom keyboard IME.

Comment: ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩.....

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way on Android is to use [Calcy IV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tesmath.calcy) with the renaming feature enabled, change the settings to the circled numbers and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Gokul NC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170646/how-can-you-enter-%e2%91%ae%e2%91%ad%e2%91%ac-unicode-symbols-with-a-number-in-a-circle-when-typing#comment218310_170646) and [iBug](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170646/how-can-you-enter-%e2%91%ae%e2%91%ad%e2%91%ac-unicode-symbols-with-a-number-in-a-circle-when-typing#comment218355_170646) that a special Unicode keyboard (e.g. [Unicode Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.hotmist.unicodepad)) is the answer.

Comment: My original answer contained this reminder: "Spoofing Pokémon GO is only going to get you banned nowadays. IV Calculators that use Pokémon GO APIs count as spoofing."